# counterexample of $\rho(AB) \leq \rho(A)\rho(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, examples-counterexamples, spectral-theory, spectral-radius

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are normal complex $n \times n$ matrices. Then we know that $\rho(AB) \leq \rho(A)\rho(B)$ where $\rho(.)$ is the spectral radius of a matrix.
Is there any counterexample if $A$ or $B$ is not normal?

Comment: Wait. Are you asking for examples where $\rho(AB)>\rho(A)\rho(B)$, or examples in which $\rho(AB)\le\rho(A)\rho(B)$ but $A$ and $B$ are not normal?

Answer (score 3):

Consider $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 &1 \\ 0 &0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $B = A^T$.
$\rho(A) = 0 = \rho(B)$ but $AB = \begin{bmatrix} 1 &0 \\ 0 &0 \end{bmatrix}$ then $\rho(AB)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

This almost always occurs in the Cholesky factorisation $LL^T$ of a positive semidefinite matrix. When all entries in the strictly lower triangular part of $L$ are nonzero, we have $\rho(LL^T)>\rho(L)^2$.